# validar nombre python

Tags: python

'buen dia, queria saber si alguien me podía decir si existe una forma de poder valida el nombre sin que el Isalpha() me de False por la presencia de espacios en blanco'

```
nombre = ""
while not nombre:
    try:
        nombre = input("Ingrese nombre: ")
        if nombre.isalpha()== False:
            nombre = ""
            raise ValueError()
    except ValueError:
        print("el nombre no puede contener numeros o signos")
        pass
```

Comment: Después del `input` pon esta línea: `nombre = nombre.replace(' ', '')`.

Comment: excelente, muchas gracias